# A special little twist

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer is 9 letters in total.

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer (which also describes the diagram) is:

> **GOLDEN PIE**!

Why? First note that starting from the top of the 24-spoked circle and moving clockwise (in the direction of the arrow):

> the 16th and 21st sections are indicated by the two 5x5 grids. In fact, it is possible to shade squares that lie between cells of the same colour to leave white-space that forms the shapes of **pi** and **phi**, the **16th and 21st letters of the Greek alphabet** (which has 24 letters in total - the number of segments in our spoked circle...).
>
>  [image: Drawing PHI and PI]

What do these mean?

> Well, apart from being Greek letters they are also famously **mathematical constants**, with phi (also known as the '[Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)') taking the value 1.61803... and pi taking the value 3.14...

Applying this information, we can derive the final answer by noticing that:

> the figure of pi was constructed using 3 different blocks of colour and the figure of phi using 6 different blocks of colour. If we therefore take *the first 6 digits of phi and the first 3 digits of pi* and look for letters in the appropriately coloured grids below (blue for phi, red for pi, as per the borders of their dot grids) we can spell out the thematic words **GOLDEN** and **PIE** - which is exactly what the 24-spoked circle looks like!
>
>  [image: Spelling out GOLDEN PIE]

Comment: That was... fast :D Well done!